# Qt - QPSQL Driver not loaded: Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, qt, driver

I have been trying to connect to a remote SQL database with Qt 6.5.2, using QtSql which came included with Qt. The SQLite driver (already installed) won't allow me to connect to a remote SQL database, so I've tried downloading the MySQL and QPSQL drivers which can connect remotely and in both cases it kept giving me the error

> QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
>  QSqlDatabase: available
> drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
>  Error: Could not open database

I have downloaded the qsqlpsql.dll file in the application directory and project directory - as well as in the /plugins/sqldrivers/ folder, but i still have this error. Can someone please help? I have seen other people with the "driver not loaded" error but they usually had compatibility errors, but there is none of that to be seen as far as I'm aware.

P.S. I have also tried downloading on RHEL9 - which is the OS that the sql database is on - but i don't think that is too relevant

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems you have not copied the DLLs distributed by Postgres (from the `bin\` folder where PostgreSQL is installed) to the folder with your executable. The required DLL are:

- libpq.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libintl-`X`.dll (`X` being a number)
- libiconv-2.dll

Comment: Are those files only accessible if I have Postgres downloaded? I don't have it downloaded on my PC - it is on a seperate server and I'm developing on my personal PC. Do I need to download the PostgreSQL on here too? Or is there a repo to get them?

Comment: If you don't have a DBA to retrieve the DLLs for you, then you need to download Postgres indeed. I wouldn't trust DLLs downloaded from another source.